# How to access ArrayList data to ListView which is having multiple textview and image icon in Android?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-listview, listadapter

I had created an ArrayList which contains data responsed by server. Now Arraylist having all data which I preffered. But I want to display these data to list view.

Ex: ['videoName','VideoCategory','Thumbnail path']

This is arraylist:

```
mydata=['a1','science','/playback/2012/09_im.jpg','a2','maths','/playback/2012/01.jpg'.....]
```

Now I want to display 'videoName' in textView1 and 'VideoCategory' in textView2 and 'Thumbnail Path' to image icon.

I am trying ArrayList Adapter. But there are several problem occured.

Please Help me...

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8294930/593709)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a custom `ListView` and you have to use `BaseAdapter` for this. This is the link of a example of custom `ListView`:

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/multiple-listview-and-custom-listview.html

```
set   list.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    public  class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {


            ViewHolder holder; 
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            Activity context = null;

            public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;












            public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


            }


            public int getCount() {
                return one.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);



                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                    holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                    holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.B);
                    holder.btn.setFocusable(false);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }







                holder.text.setText(one.get(position));
                holder.text1.setText("Stall No: "+two.get(position));







                return convertView;

            }



            class ViewHolder {
                TextView text;
                TextView text1;
                ImageView image;
                Button btn;


            }
```

Now use whatever you want is your `ListView`.

Comment: I want to display "a1" to 'textview1' and "science" to 'textView2' and so on.. How to set customAdapter view ?